# Where can I find an English translation of the text of the Belovezh Accords?

Tags: soviet-union, treaties

It is reported in many places on the internet that the decision to abolish the Soviet Union was made in the Belovezh Forest in Belarus, near Poland, by the heads of government of three of the Soviet republics: Belarus, Russia, and Ukraine, and that on December 8, 1991 they signed the [Belovezh accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belovezh_Accords) in the forest declaring the USSR abolished.

Via Google I could not find any text of the document. Is a translation into English somewhere accessible via the internet?

Comment: Well, you can take the text in Russian (say, [here](https://www.cvce.eu/en/collections/unit-content/-/unit/df06517b-babc-451d-baf6-a2d4b19c1c88/e000eaf0-b51a-41bd-bba9-5228ce95b7a6/Resources#d1eb7a8c-4868-4da6-9098-3175c172b9bc_en&overlay)) and then use your favorite online (or off-line) translation program.

Comment: @MoisheKohan : I don't find any texts in Russian or Belarusian when I click on your link.

Comment: [Wikipedia references](https://doc.histrf.ru/20/soglashenie-o-sozdanii-sodruzhestva-nezavisimykh-gosudarstv/) the Russian text

Comment: @MichaelHardy  Odd, it's right there, with English title "Agreement  establishing..."

Comment: Of course any English translation would necessarily be an approximation (languages do not map perfectly to each other), so if you were hoping to see find some interesting legal technicalities, you'd need to read it in the original language.

Comment: @MoisheKohan : ok, Now I click on your link and I find an entirely different page from what I saw when I clicked on it on several occasions a number of hours ago. This time I see a Cyrillic document.